# Server closing connection after ssh login

Tags: ssh, arch-linux

Working on archlinux, last updated today. Tried to setup a web application on the server. Got error 'core dumped' when tried su, decided to reboot. After reboot the problem started.

ssh -vvv output after I input my password(can provide full log if needed):

```
Last login: Tue Nov  1 02:16:34 2022 from 192.168.1.100
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_write (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-signal reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o3 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug3: Successfully set console output code page from 65001 to 65001
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from 65001 to 65001
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/6 sock -1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
debug3: Successfully set console output code page from 65001 to 65001
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from 65001 to 65001
Connection to 192.168.1.3 closed.
Transferred: sent 1916, received 2684 bytes, in 0.6 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 3460.9, received 4848.1
debug1: Exit status -1
```

Tried to play with -t param.

ls outputs `go`, cat /etc/passwd `file not found`, cd and a lot of other commands: `command not found`

Have no idea what happened, as well as what to do.

Also, I have physical acess to the machine, but would like to stay in ssh(it's kinda difficult).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very stupid.

I've tried a lot of different solutions to fix this, but the answer was quickly press ctrl+c after login. Then, I could do my stuff.

I remember like I tried to install some yum packages, or something like that, and after a week noticed the problem(didn't checked server after reboot). Maybe update freezed the system?. Not sure.